# angularjs directive service in the ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can anyone explain me why this works:

```
//Common directives
angular.module('mean.articles')
    .directive('checkout',['Cart', function(Cart) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template:   '<div data-ng-repeat="item in items">' +
            '<div class="clearfix item-box">'+
            '<div class="col-md-2 text-left item-pic"><img class="img-responsive img-rounded" alt="{{item.title}}" data-ng-src="/public/upload/{{item.pic}}"></div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-2 text-left item-quantity">{{item.quantity}}</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 text-left item-title">{{item.title}}</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 text-right item-tot" data-subtot="{{item.price * item.quantity}}">{{item.price * item.quantity}}</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>',
            link: function( scope , element , attributes ) {
                scope.items = Cart.get();
            }   
        };
    }]);
```

and this doesn't work

```
//Common directives
angular.module('mean.articles')
    .directive('checkout',['Cart', function(Cart) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template:   '<div data-ng-repeat="item in Cart.get()">' +
            '<div class="clearfix item-box">'+
            '<div class="col-md-2 text-left item-pic"><img class="img-responsive img-rounded" alt="{{item.title}}" data-ng-src="/public/upload/{{item.pic}}"></div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-2 text-left item-quantity">{{item.quantity}}</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 text-left item-title">{{item.title}}</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 text-right item-tot" data-subtot="{{item.price * item.quantity}}">{{item.price * item.quantity}}</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>',
            link: function( scope , element , attributes ) {

            }   
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The template has only access to its `scope`.**

The second example does not work because the template has no access to any services. Services like `Cart` are only available in the `link` method of the directive.